# automatic tweet fill (quote) in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to link js to html so that when user clicks tweet icon it automatically fills up the tweet box in twitter...my code is only opening the box but not filling it...any suggestions?

```
function makeId() {
   var rNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
   $("#quote > h1").html(quotes[rNumber]);
 }
$("#press").on('click', function() {
  $("#quote > h1").fadeOut('slow', function(){
  makeId();
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');
 });
});
$("#icon > a").click(function(){
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" +  makeId());
})
```

my whole code is here - https://codepen.io/buzz_lightyear/pen/gXLLpo?editors=1010

Comment: You should return something from makeId() function

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it for you, instead of creating / selecting a new ID you needed to add the value of the current ID to the url.

```
$("#icon > a").click(function(){
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" +  makeId());
})
```

should be replaced with

```
$("#icon > a").click(function(){
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + $("#quote > h1").html());
})
```

Comment: it's not working...all i'm getting is an empty tweet box but not the quote in it

Comment: i've edited your codepen and it works. Did you press the rerun button?